# Nothing happens in my code though it could be correct

Tags: javascript, html

I've no clue what should I add or change in my code. This program is considered to output 'correct' when you text in current year '2023' but I don't get any errors or anything else. It just doesn't work.
P.S it outputs 'incorrect' even if it's true

```js
const date = new Date();
const input = document.querySelector('.js-input').value;
const button = document.querySelector('.js-button');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

button.addEventListener('click', yearfunc);

function yearfunc(event) {
  if (input == date.getFullYear()) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    button.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', div);
    div.innerText = 'Correct';
  } else {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    button.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', div);
    div.innerText = 'Incorrect';
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<p>What the year is it right now?</p><br><br>
<input type="text" class="js-input">
<button class="js-button">Send</button>
```

Comment: Try retrieving the value of `.js-input` from inside your event handler.

Comment: Also note: If you want to always cancel an event in a function, do so at the very beginning of the function, that way even mistakes in the function would still cancel the event. This is mostly useful in form submission validations or AJAX. In YOUR case, if the buttons are not in  a form you do not need to preventDefault in the function. However to be on the safe side in case you wrap them in a form later, always make buttons that are not needed to submit `type="button"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that you assigned '.value' too early in the code.
Assigning it directly in the function and comparing using a new variable solves the problem, try this out:

```js
const date = new Date();
const input = document.querySelector(".js-input");
const button = document.querySelector(".js-button");

button.addEventListener("click", yearfunc);

function yearfunc(event) {
  const value = input.value;
  console.log(`VALUE: `, value);
  console.log(`YEAR: `, date.getFullYear());
  if (value == date.getFullYear()) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    button.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", div);
    div.innerText = "Correct";
  } else {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    button.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", div);
    div.innerText = "Incorrect";
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<p>What year is it right now?</p>
<br /><br />
<input type="number" class="js-input" />
<button class="js-button">Send</button>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you Are retrieving the input outside of event so when the event actually occurs you are just comparing a pre-loaded value of "". Solution is to fetch the input data inside event handler:

```
// JavaScript code
const button = document.querySelector('.js-button');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
button.addEventListener('click', yearfunc);

function yearfunc(event) {
  const date = new Date();
  const input = document.querySelector('.js-input').value; 
    if(input == date.getFullYear()) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        button.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', div);
        div.innerText = 'Correct';
    }

    else {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        button.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', div);
        div.innerText = 'Incorrect';
    }

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. The way value was being taken from the 'js-input' class, was not giving the correct input value.

```
const date = new Date();
const input1 = document.getElementsByClassName("js-input");
const button = document.querySelector('.js-button');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

button.addEventListener('click', yearfunc);

function yearfunc(event) {
  console.log("in the function")
  console.log(input1[0].value)
  console.log(date.getFullYear())
    if(input1[0].value == String(date.getFullYear())) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        button.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', div);
        div.innerText = 'Correct';
    }

    else {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        button.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', div);
        div.innerText = 'Incorrect';
    }

  event.preventDefault();
}
```